# CDDVD drawer opens immediately after closing in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, cd-drive

I don't use the internal DVD drive often, but when I used it last night each time I closed the drawer the drawer opens immediately. I thought the drive might have gone bad, but I exactly the same behavior with an external drive as well.
Note: I tried the external DVD drive on a different machine running Debian and it doesn't exhibit this behavior.

What I've looked at so far:

```
sudo setcd -s /dev/sr0

  Auto close tray:     set
  Auto open tray:      cleared
  Use O_NONBLOCK flag: set
  Lock tray:           set
  Check CD type:       set
```

I tried changing the settings using setcd. The only change that seemed to have any effect was

```
sudo setcd -f0 /dev/sr0
```

which clears the "Use O_NONBLOCK flag."

```
  Auto close tray:     set
  Auto open tray:      cleared
  Use O_NONBLOCK flag: cleared
  Lock tray:           set
  Check CD type:       set
```

When the "Use O_NONBLOCK flag" is set using

```
sudo setcd -f1 /dev/sr0
```

the problem resumes.

I tried

```
sudo udevadm monitor
```

with the Use O_NONBLOCK flag set, and there was a flood of messages like the ones below. This make me think that something is wrong with the driver or some obscure setting got changed someplace after a software update.

```
KERNEL[7862.150043] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
UDEV  [7862.627306] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sr0 (block)
```

I'm not quite sure what's going on with the DVD drive, or possibly the driver. I am open to suggestions for a fix.

Thank you!

More info:
With a disk in the drive,

```
sudo lshw -C disk
```

Shows this:

```
*-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: BD-ROM  BDC-TD02
       vendor: PIONEER
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       logical name: /media/someone/somedisk
       version: 1.02
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,norock,check=r,map=n,blocksize=2048,uid=1001,gid=1001,dmode=500,fmode=400 state=mounted status=ready
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/cdrom
          logical name: /media/someone/somedisk
          configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,norock,check=r,map=n,blocksize=2048,uid=1001,gid=1001,dmode=500,fmode=400 state=mounted
```

Comment: This might be useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1363346/why-is-wake-from-suspend-suddenly-ejecting-my-cd-tray

Answer (score 1):

FYI: This looks like it was a boot image or kernel problem.

Ubuntu did update this morning (2021-09-27). CD/DVD repeatedly ejecting problem seems to be fixed in boot image:

```
Linux 5.4.0-87-generic
```

Running

setcd -s /dev/sr0

Shows these as the default settings for the DVD drive (above) in my original question:

```
  Auto close tray:     set
  Auto open tray:      cleared
  Use O_NONBLOCK flag: set
  Lock tray:           cleared
  Check CD type:       cleared
```

Problem still exists in both of these boot images:

```
Linux 5.4.0-86-generic
Linux 5.4.0-84-generic
```

The temporary workaround for the two boot images above is:

```
sudo setcd -f0 /dev/sr0
```

which will temporarily change the Use O_NONBLOCK flag to "cleared" and stop the drive from immediately opening the drawer after it's closed.